# Error when using CRM as source dataset in ADF v2

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, odata, azure-data-factory

I am currently working on an adf v2 project. And on one of my pipelines, I am running a copy activity that retrieves data from an Odata source (connecting to a CRM instance) and transfers it to an Azure SQL Database. When I preview the data in the source, it successfully retrieves all of the data, but when I run the activity it returns an error like this: *"Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException,Message=The given key was not present in the dictionary.,Source=mscorlib adfv2 error"*

Is this an ongoing issue with adf v2 or there is actually a missing attribute in the crm source side ?

Thanks for answering everyone

Comment: Could you share the activity id？

Comment: hi is this the activity id ?
a7d28542-555e-49ea-87b9-339c74f06bdb

Is it the same with the pipeline run id ?

Answer (score -1):

Any reason why you didn't choose the Dynamics CRM connector over OData? The former is more recommended in ADF.

Comment: The source is a Dynamics AX, I also used the oob connector but the error still persists